# Dynamic array of strings in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, malloc

I am trying to grow an array of strings in C dynamically, but I get Segmentation Faults when I try to get the allocated data (not when assigning). This is part of a more complex code and is simplified, files[i].file_id is correct and of type `char *`.

```
char **names;

names = malloc(sizeof(char *));
files = fileslog_get(FLOG_STATE_NEWOUT, -1);
i = 0;
while(files[i].file_id != NULL)
{
    if(stat(files[i].file_id, &st) > 0 && st.st_size < 64100)
    {
        if(i != 0)
            names = realloc(names, (i+1)*sizeof(char *));

        names[i] = malloc(256);

        strcpy(names[i], files[i].file_id);
    }
    ++i;
}

tot_files = i;
```

A valid version would also be having a dynamic array of strings of size 256, but I could not even compile it (using `char *names[256]` and deleting the `malloc(256)` it did not even compile).

Comment: And what exactly is the line you get your segfault in? You're not testing if your allocation worked.. are you sure it did?

Comment: nor is there any test that `files` is not NULL on the return result assignment of `fileslog_get()` And you don't need to initially `malloc` the `names` var. An initial value of `NULL` will work. See [`realloc()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc), specifically the NULL case. Post the source of `fileslog_get()`, of which I currently have very little faith, and as long as you're doing that. an *complete* compilable example demonstrating yur problem.

Comment: Exactly, so i believe our point is that it is very likely that you corrupt your memory somewhere but we cannot tell you because we don't see whole picture.

Comment: What has been your debugging strategy so far?  Have you run this under a debugger (e.g. GDB) to get a backtrace of where the crash happens?

Comment: What happens if you turn on a bunch of compiler warnings?  e.g. for GCC: `-Wall` and even `-Wextra`.  These give useful insight to potential problems in your code.

Comment: The code you've posted is OK, the error must be elsewhere. You should definitely check `strlen(files[i].file_id) < 256`; if one of those is overflowing it would explain your problems. In fact, `names[i] = malloc( strlen(files[i].file_id) + 1 );` may be appropriate.

Comment: Finally the problem was in a misuse of indexes (when the if was not satisfied, the index was increased anyway, it was solved by the use of two indexes). Also I was checking the return value of `stat` as `> 0`, when I should check `== 0`. So I was trying to read allocated but not set memory postions. Thank you for your answers!